# Flipping Cards Issue with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the flipping cards, the RotationY causes a white space - sometimes - while resizing the browser.

Please keep in mind that I must keep using percentage for the parent div, I mean the same grid style showing in the Fiddle below.

I already flipped all the boxes to see the problem after it gets flipped, so you can resize the window and see the gabs caused.

[image]

```
  <div id="card" class="flipped">
     <figure class="front">Front</figure>
     <figure class="back">Back</figure>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z6znny1q/

Please take a look http://bahaasamir.me/test.mov

Comment: where is the code that do the flip ? there is nothing in the jsfiddle

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://jsfiddle.net/z6znny1q/

Comment: It still doesn't flip

Comment: it's the same you put in your answer, there is no flipping, only static HTML/CSS

Comment: I already flipped it to see how it looks after flipping. The class .flipped added to all boxes already.

Comment: I tested it manually. However, I don't see any whitespace when flipping

Comment: If you add the javascript it's easier for us to see the problem and determine the solution.

Comment: Guys, please take a look! http://bahaasamir.me/test.mov

Comment: @AceInteract Not when flipping. when all boxes are already flipped, the spaces appear while resizing the browser only. bahaasamir.me/test.mov

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I think the problem is this class:

```
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Change `width:100%` to `width:100px` (or 200px some number).
When you use % containers resize based on their parent containers (and the browser window).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you do 3d transforms . 
One workaround would be to use a `1px` border with the color of your cards ( if that is possible )

For example, with the code provided by you, this would be a solution

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.os_set {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50% 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 0;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.os_box {
  line-height: 203px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 99;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

#card .front {
  background: #fff;
}

#card .back {
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    border:1px solid #ccc; /* added this */
}

#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="os_set">

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="os_box">
    <div id="card" class="flipped">
      <figure class="front">Front</figure>
      <figure class="back">Back</figure>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```